# How to implement if-else condition in JoltTransforms in Apache NiFi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am preparing the jolt specification where I need to implement if-else condition but I am unable to achieve it. Please help me out.

Note :

1. if `application-component-node` object is coming in the input,
   then print that and drop `application-component` and `application`(if all three application object coming input).
2. if `application-component` object is coming in the input, then
   print that and drop `application` object (if all two
   application object arrays coming input).
3. if `application` object is only coming in the input, then print
   that.

For Example:

```json
[
  {
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "type": "POLICY_CONTINUES_CRITICAL",
    "affectedEntities": [
      {
        "entityType": "POLICY",
        "name": "Exception Per Minute",
        "entityId": 3683
      },
      {
        "entityType": "APPLICATION",
        "name": "Teashop",
        "entityId": 6026
      },
      {
        "entityType": "APPLICATION-Component",
        "name": "Teashop",
        "entityId": 602667
      }
    ],
    "subType": "OVERALL_APPLICATION",
    "id": 92876278,
    "triggeredEntity": null
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "type": "POLICY_CONTINUES_CRITICAL",
    "affectedEntities": [
      {
        "entityType": "APPLICATION-Component",
        "name": "Teashop",
        "entityId": 602667
      }
    ],
    "subType": "OVERALL_APPLICATION",
    "id": 92876278,
    "triggeredEntity": null
  }
]
```

Here the expected output is `application-component-node` and drop the other two application object arrays

The priority among three object arrays is as follows:

- Priority 1 is for `application-component-node` and,
- Priority 2 is for `application-component` and,
- Priority 3 is for `application`

Note : Three object arrays are dynamic and they might come sometime only two object arrays come and sometimes only one object array may come.

Comment: `"entityType": "POLICY"` is neither in the first list nor in the priority list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ***lastElement*** function in a **modify** spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "others.&",
        "app*": {
          "@": "app[].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "app": "=lastElement(@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[0].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit** : You can alternatively use the following transformation with
firstElement function in a modify spec based on your last edit :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "aff*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&2.@(1,entityType).&" // reconstruct subobjects with entityType keys
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // used for sorting purposes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "affectedEntities": {
        "APPLICATION-Component-Node": "&1[]",
        "APPLICATION-Component": "&1[]",
        "APPLICATION": "&1[]",
        "POLICY": "&1[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "aff*": "=firstElement(@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```

where the case-sensitivity of the `entityType`s matter. The listing within the last **shift** transformation is used to order by those given entity types as in their presented letter cases.

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: But now the input is changed , I have updated my question pls Check and help me out @Barbaros Ozhan